# UITableView background black and empty cells black on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode7-beta3

Xcode 7.0b3
iOS Deployment Target 8.0

Here's the test app I made to isolate the issue.

Created a `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.  Tap a cell, and pushes another one of those table view controllers.  This table view controller has a random number of sections and rows in each section.

On iPhone running iOS 9, table scrolls correctly... empty cells are while.
On iPhone running iOS 8, table has black background.  Empty rows are black instead of white.

In our "real" app, we sometimes see contents of old UITableView in a new UITableView.  So I tried to isolate the issue to see if its a bug building with the Xcode 7 beta.

Does this sound like a bug building with the beta xcode and using iOS 8?  Or did we create a bug/doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's a beta bug. My app that used to work fine suddenly stopped working and segues does not get triggered correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in Xcode 7 beta 3. Temporary workaround was to set `tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`.

As of Xcode 7 beta 4 issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: Except now this fix broke something else for me :)  Thanks for the confirmation.